# Splitting equation

Tags: align

I'm trying to split an equation into two parts, but when I adding a double slash `\\` I get this error

> There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error. If there are
> LaTeX errors shown below or in the raw logs, please try
> to fix them and compile again.
> The document environment contains no content. If it’s
> empty, please add some content and compile again.
> This project contains a file called output.pdf.
> If that file exists, please rename it and compile again.

```
\begin{multline}
    \Gamma_{2} = \Gamma \qty(a+q \xleftrightarrow{} g + q)  +  \Gamma \qty(a + \bar{q} \xleftrightarrow{} g + \bar{q}) = 
      \frac{\alpha_{s}^{3}}{F_{a}^{2}}~T^{3}~2N_{f}~\frac{\xi(3)}{4~\pi^{4}}\qty[\frac{1}{4}\qty(9 + \ln4 - 6\gamma + \\ 6\frac{\xi^{\prime}(3)}{\xi(3)}) + \frac{9}{4} - \frac{3}{2}\gamma + \frac{3}{2}\frac{\xi^{\prime}(3)}{\xi(3)} -\frac{3}{2}\ln(2\pi \alpha_{s}) - \frac{15}{8} ]
\end{multline}
```

Comment: Please post a full (yet minimal) compilable example, not just a code snippet.

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more context. Like the error says the the errors are in the raw logs. Also the MWE should be added (preamble and so on).

Comment: What exactly is `\qty`? Additionally in math mode ` ' = ^{\prime} ` so no need to write that much

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly clear what your desired output is, but maybe this will get you started.

- Use `align` instead of `multline`
- control delimiter sizes using `big`, `Big`, `bigg`, etc.
- remove `~` spaces
- break long line where you choose
- use `\xi'` not `\xi^{\prime}`
- I don't know what `\qty` is so I removed it. Maybe some macro? Posting a complete ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) will help others help you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \Gamma_{2} &= \Gamma (a+q \leftrightarrow g + q)  +  \Gamma (a + \bar{q} \leftrightarrow g + \bar{q}) \notag\\
    & = \frac{\alpha_{s}^{3}}{F_{a}^{2}}T^{3}2N_{f}\frac{\xi(3)}{4\pi^{4}}\biggl[\frac{1}{4}\Bigl(9 + \ln4 - 6\gamma + 6\frac{\xi'(3)}{\xi(3)}\Bigr) + \frac{9}{4}\notag \\
    &\qquad -\frac{3}{2}\gamma + \frac{3}{2}\frac{\xi'(3)}{\xi(3)} -\frac{3}{2}\ln(2\pi \alpha_{s}) - \frac{15}{8} \biggr]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! it works

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that employs a single `multline` environment. I've replaced some of the mysterious `\qty` macros -- they don't seem to have any relation to the `\qty` macro of the [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) package -- with explicit sizing instructions for the round parentheses and square brackets in some cases; in the first row, though, I've chosen *not* to make any sizing adjustments. I've further replaced (a) both instances of the needlessly complex `\xleftrightarrow{}` with `\leftrightarrow` and (b) both instances of `^{\prime}` with `'`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'multline' environment
\usepackage{old-arrows} % optional (smaller arrow heads)
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\Gamma_{\!2} 
  = \Gamma (a+q \leftrightarrow g+q )  \,
    \Gamma (a+\bar{q} \leftrightarrow g+\bar{q} ) \\[\jot]
  = \frac{\alpha_{s}^{3}}{F_{a}^{2}} \, T^{3} \, 2N_{\!f} 
    \frac{\xi(3)}{4 \pi^{4}} \biggl[ \frac{1}{4} 
    \biggl( 9 + \ln4 - 6\gamma + 6\frac{\xi'(3)}{\xi(3)} \biggr) \\
    + \frac{9}{4} - \frac{3}{2}\gamma + \frac{3}{2}\frac{\xi'(3)}{\xi(3)} 
    - \frac{3}{2}\ln(2\pi \alpha_{s}) - \frac{15}{8} \biggr]
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping!it works